# 3 dimensional GUMBEL COPULA

Tags: database, dependencies, aggregation, tail

I'm working with a DB concerning insurance losses coming from different businesses.

How could I generate randomly a three dimensional *gumbel* copula to aggregate three Lines of Business? I don't know the tau parameter, but I have only the Pearson correlation coefficient between these two sectors. Unfortunately I used the closed relation typical of Gaussian Copula between the Pearson rho and the tau parameter:

```
{tau=(2/pi)*asin(rho)}
```

This is a great proxy; how can I do alternatively?
Furthermore, I tried to implement the rHAC function (in the "HAC" package) that allows me to generate directly a 3 dimensional copula; after that I used the quantile function to obtain the new value to be summed up

```
{quantile(db[,1],probs=gumbel[,1]);
 quantile(db[,2],probs=gumbel[,2]), 
 etc...
}
```

Otherwise, I tried to utilize also this function

```
rCopula(N_gumbel,gumbelCopula(1/(1- tau),dim=2))
```

which requires a hierarchical structure:
first of all I have to aggregate `(A,B)` and then `(A+B,C)`. At this stage the function `quantile` is needed again. In both the cases, the correlation matrix is:

```
matrix(c(1,0.5,0.25,0.5,1,0.25,0.25,0.25,1),nrow=3,ncol=3)
```

I noticed that the correlation between the elements generated randomly is not perfectly equal to the original value. Moreover, the correlation between the cash amounts (generated after the quantile function) is higher than the exact one (defined as hypothesis).

This fact creates a huge problems. The results of that aggregation are similar to those obtained through a Gaussian Copula. This is impossible!

The process is:

1. Problem with the tau (I have only the `rho` pearson and I don't want to fit it)
2. Problem with the random generation function. At the end I can notice an incoherence.

I'm very thankful for all the advice.

Comment: I prettified the whole question. Feel free to improve further.